# getting error while generating JWT signed token for rs256 and rsa private key

Tags: c#, encryption, jwt, rsa, rs256

My target is generate JWT token using RS256 algorithm using RSA private key. My steps for this:

I have generated a rsa private key using following command:

```
openssl genrsa -out private_key.pem 2048
```

after that I write below code to generate JWT token:

```
 var claims = ......(list of claims)...
 string privateKey = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\FazlaElahiMdJubayer\private_key.pem");
 CreateToken(privateKey, claims);

 private static void CreateToken(string privateKey, List<Claim> claims)
    {
        RSAParameters rsaParams;
        using (var tr = new StringReader(privateKey))
        {
            var pemReader = new PemReader(tr);
            var keyPair = pemReader.ReadObject() as AsymmetricCipherKeyPair;
            if (keyPair == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Could not read RSA private key");
            }
            var privateRsaParams = keyPair.Private as RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters;
            rsaParams = DotNetUtilities.ToRSAParameters(privateRsaParams);
        }
        using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            rsa.ImportParameters(rsaParams);
            Dictionary<string, object> payload = claims.ToDictionary(k => k.Type, v => (object)v.Value);
            var token = Jose.JWT.Encode(payload, rsa, Jose.JwsAlgorithm.RS256);
        }
    }
```

but somehow the keyPair is null and throw `Could not read RSA private key` even though my code successfully read the private key from the .pem file. Is there anything wrong with my private key? What steps I am missing?
my private key is below:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEvAIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKYwggSiAgEAAoIBAQCu7awWqTY3RtPT
APwkC/4ufWSEkm/fieobjkZHUjpUU836me1enYncEXJue6t9bB7SQck7THgG1O12
jxT9mCbQWSmwdWUpIj6AvGkyAGuMAJzfzrU0x95SJEtIjOnIA0gPQQ3UR7oKgO7I
K2z40qpuy9l2NxZ1YxffBRkqpV16LHD9KuFOsd0iMWnViJI3yLqsUMwOKaj+L9aR
yCGGZ0Y8oFBCzZyY5irtyVHlzlI+kZRmi4N3ZxAEmXYVO4jOtlIj47RpK3WWBEGa
kTLkdTLkMaR/WCHIhvOl/vtgK0PEc18+fbFGUlOiPuIqyXGtnzOPdvVm2WCF+U25
eoxCbjJbAgMBAAECggEAOZf8HFvrA0kZDfRZj964+gKD+VgjaFSGlTsDLZFHriMH
gtZyPkAdNy0xYWnrXPifrzdEs3bqX8l0Q6A5V4NkaB2rKbOFMoVZUdZ2xiU4Q5ii
DdgHdlDGBIJ5nPH0OMvHymnvTTCucq3fsF0H3Ga0AZWxTAg4Jz8QiXeqwQ1AGSyD
DVPOaj7tsBmTMm/HfhTmv5yKkRXDANChjOwdP/iHn4YMuyWLqR9GbLJElVP1WnGm
die9n7H56e9MydwC56tW13I5DBEqZWBAGi0Am8/qwO5Ne66zPpjMBzXvXzUY4MYj
HflH7xA5tGA6TNwQKP9/Fm/1j6GseAVLrVJyWeeIUQKBgQC5AmKPOu4AW6/NL3kD
wERjzAw7NCLej5jZ9tCCdogsCApRB1atSD9LDCPVUNXFfMhDPDpO+Ybg2Zb5pSVr
vOXA+1wbvEPv2Qdtvqv5ricshcBLARjaKr0RwKUH6yzG4DjkvE2QnS3KV+XVROVn
n73J7gBrA/8B6r1iM/kU2hDfsQKBgQDyDQgFyirVKggzsRnHQzJxVsmxKAqrV0Zo
GC4hINoPGAzqNma2ekEk8X6m2lu1cMWHDgraV55OktlC4HFdLn/d1VTFKy88b0mD
HK2+OVd62PzO94DQBYddPfi2ATAaXFv7/8ijHZB3v3vnxJbtd3haoROwIAfu0EUW
tLG0SmchywKBgCTuHvJsVvnnU25n3YYsKPqqzn466AL5Mw+/PtvsAT6Y1EZcaqbo
VwoKAFUib6meQPN64EDHem8DwClRF+krqckd48L9j6oe7mavuvB6HQO8JyhRrb5O
7bLPe6HbBfMk6vZtyCXn2i4b4Zryx8ApmN7oDVlPUOX3D5q8uSm6ZcfhAoGAGvYg
oqR2SPA5oahkerGdeMp2BOm05oj+KrIm0UHbiDrhlWUh48mSYA8WUHeaJ4e8OOLz
ioaf95ib4rslZX+8dnVA0AWTaWPsCFK1d67jc6ef4V3oV0OGZHh2r69KMGWBSXyg
WKr+YJhPsO1Q8nqQSWgPzVqEB7HjQDg4YyC2hCkCgYBsUur/iqsG4oHwFdEFLEgH
TLgjkcuJZfdKkgz4zOJS2jwnTKV1gfS1UAEA1vNs9qmX71FzV/Su55Fgr1feljef
LBrHllWAWRHQNcRsjIOljLcF3yCsE5NZsn9HPEFlhYIMXi5ZbDpWvSkO7zp9QQNa
ci9m4h9FKl2AjrWWco32yQ==
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

and my claims are like this:

```
var claims = new[]
        {
            new Claim("partnerUrl", "https://www.my-domain.com"),
            new Claim("offerId", "adsaddsadadsad"),
            new Claim("returnUrl", "https://demo.com/lend/"),
            new Claim("expireOn", "2006-09-18T00:00:00.000Z"),
        };
```

Comment: Maybe it is worth trying to read the file directly as stream: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72260086 instead of first loading it as string and then reading the key from that string. Bascially try `var tr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\FazlaElahiMdJubayer\private_key.pem")`

Comment: Your key has the PKCS#8 format, the code requires the PKCS#1 format. You can convert the key online, e.g. [here](https://8gwifi.org/pemconvert.jsp) (for security reasons not for productive keys), or create a key in PKCS#1 format *directly* with OpenSSL or adapt the code (the latter depends on the .NET version, which you should also specify).

Comment: @Topaco after converting to PKCS#1 it works, however the token I got showing invalid signature in this https://jwt.io/ website, any idea why  my code generating invalid signature?

Comment: I can verify the generated token on *https://jwt.io/* using your code and private key (with my own `claims`). Why it doesn't work for you can probably be answered if you provide the missing information: `claims`-part of the code, generated token, public key used (and private key if different from the posted one).

Comment: @Topaco i have added my claims, could you please check in the question again

Comment: Works for me. RS256 is deterministic, post the generated token for comparison. Check if the public key is valid (i.e. related to the private one) or post it.

Comment: how you generate public key after converting to PKCS#1 ?  @Topaco

Comment: anyway it works for me after generating public key from new private key @Topaco

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252790/discussion-between-fazla-elahi-md-jubayer-and-topaco).